# Hidden div by Country code

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

I'm not a php-hero so, I try to hidden a section if the user not come from a specific country.

So I did this:

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#country").html(response.country);
}, "jsonp");

<input hidden id="country" type="text" name="country" value="">
```

This work well and show me the country code (eg. IT).
Now I try to get this value and insert in a IF

```
$country = $_GET['country'];
$it = "IT";

<?php if ($country != $it): ?>
    Code to hidden here...
<?php endif; ?>
```

What is it wrong here?

Comment: How do you send the `$_GET['country'];` from browser to server?

Comment: server, in the php page.

Comment: Have you tried an `echo $country;`?

Comment: yes the problem is this, js and php in this way doesn't communicate well.

Comment: Can you post more `code`.

Comment: It's just this, inside the condition `if` there are a html `<div>` in the div there are a bit of things like slideshow, text, cta... How I can give to the `$country` the value of the input with out send any data in ajax?

Comment: You can do a `<form>` and `submit` it. Or use `AJAX`. There is no other way. Unfortunately.

Comment: thank you @ajax for your help I see that it's a bit tricky!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$("#country").html(response.country);
```

to

```
$("#country").val(response.country);
```

Because php `$_GET` saves values.

Also I do not see a reason to do this:

```
$it = "IT";
<?php if ($country != $it): ?>
```

You can just do

```
<?php if ($country != "IT"): ?>
```

And last but not least you should not access `$_GET` directly. It is better to use function `filter_input` which in your case would be `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'country')`

**EDIT**

I do not understand what is the hidden input for. But if you want to show or hide content depending on the country, and you get the country using ajax there is absolutely no need for this input.

Instead of making php condition (`<?php if ($country != "IT")...`) You can do it in js. Let's say that inside your condition there is a `div` with class `content`

**Solution**

Your html would look more or less like this

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- Your content here -->
</div>
```

instead of php condition.

And in js you can do something like this

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    if (response.country == "IT") {
        $(".content").hide();
    }
}, "jsonp");
```

**So what do we do here?**

We check if country code equals "IT". If it is true we hide the content. And this is the same what you were doing in php (if country different than IT show content).

**EDIT 2**

Instead of hiding the div you can remove it

```
$(".content").remove();
```

Comment: yes .val need to work, but only with html I can see the value. Probably if I use val I need also to echo the val inside the input val tag, correct?

Comment: I have to hidden the div under input, what is inside the `if` I use the input just to take the val to give in a php var

Comment: @MarcoRomano No, if you change value of input what you see will also change. But this input is hidden so that is the reason why you do not see it.

Comment: @MarcoRomano You can not have more than one elements with the samie id on page.

Comment: the problem is the `$country` not get the input value

Comment: It depends on what you do. If this hidden `input` is inside a `form` then after form submit it should work properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170589/discussion-between-krzysztof-janiszewski-and-marco-romano).

Comment: Yes this work. Thank you. It's not the best way just hide the div. So you have reapply and I will give you the point :)

Comment: What do you mean by reapply?

Comment: I mean only that just give a `displey:none` is not the best way, because it's not a safe way. the best is not print the div completely.

Comment: Ok, so you can do `$(".content").remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Try hiding via javascript, ajax can run PHP scripts and bring it back into the DOM but you're better off using JS if you don't need a backendscript

```
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
   var country = $("#country").html(response.country);
   if(country != "IT"){ document.getElementByID("country").display = "none";
}, "jsonp");

<input hidden id="country" type="text" name="country" value="">
```

Comment: I try this. could be a grate solution.

Comment: I can't write in this way? `<?php if ($country != "IT"): ?>` because inside the if I have a lot of code. will be easier if I can give the condition to not show the content.

Comment: Do some research on AJAX, because PHP cannot interact with js retrieved variables like that

Comment: but if I use the input to take the data for the php var. this could work?

Answer (score 1):

I use the ProcessWise cms, that have their own API. So this answer work only with the [ProcessWise](https://processwire.com) cms. ( the best one ;) )

```
    <?PHP

function getUserIP()
{
    $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $client;
    }
    elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {
        $ip = $forward;
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}


$user_ip = getUserIP();

echo "ip: " . $user_ip . "<br />";

$http = new WireHttp();
$url = "http://ipinfo.io/{$user_ip}/country";
$response = $http->get($url, ['country' => '']);


echo "Country: " . $response . "<br />";
echo "Successful response: " . $sanitizer->entities($response) . "<br />";

?>
```